# Flutter: Embed a color/style into my String

Tags: flutter

In Flutter I have a `Text` widget which I pass a string to.
I'd like to embed a color into my **String** and **NOT** simply my text widget.

**Explanation**
The reason I need this behavior is that the text I intend on passing it mostly black, but I want some bits to be red or bold.

The text is passed to a Text widget inside an `AlertDialog`.

**My attempt:**

```html
final s1 = '<b>Text</b>'; // which obviously doesn't work
final s2 = 'Text1\r\nText2'; // breaks a line. Nothing to do with the color, but I thought there may be more ways to manipulate text like this
```

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using RichText widget in flutter-

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text: 'This is black text, ',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'this is red text, ',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'and this is bold text.',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Here is the official documentation for more info- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html